# Unable to use energy conservation though it's perfectly valid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, collision

> A massless rod of length $L$ connects 2 balls A and B of mass $m$ each. It is hinged at centre and free to rotate in vertical plane. A third ball C of same mass falls on B from height $h$ and sticks to it. find angular velocity of system after collision. (The rod can apply forces only along its length).

---

I could solve the question using linear momentum conservation of BC system before and after collision. Then I applied angular momentum conservation just after collision and got the right answer.

But if after conserving linear momentum of BC system, I use energy conservation, I get a different and incorrect answer. I believe this should not have been the case.

---

Here are my answers:

Using angular momentum conservation: $\sqrt{8gh}/3L$

### Using energy conservation: $4\sqrt{gh}/\sqrt 3 L$

I intend to conserve energy in the following way.

Initial kinetic energy=energy of bc system just after the collision and before rotation=1/2*2m*(v/2)^2.

Final kinetic energy=kinetic energy just after the entire abc+rod system starts rotating=1/2*3m*(l/2)^2*(angular velocity)^2

Note:::

I know elastic collision leads to energy loss. I'm conserving energy right AFTER collision but before rotation and then kinetic energy just when rotation starts

I still didn't get a proper answer please help

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106364/discussion-on-question-by-vamsi-krishna-chilakamarri-unable-to-use-energy-conser).

Comment: You cannot strictly use conservation of energy here, it wouldn't make sense as you need to use momentum conservation to find v just after impact due to the inelastic nature of the collision

Comment: Yes. First I found v just after impact and then immediately found the kinetic energy of system. This is  after the collision finished so there shouldn't be any loss now. Now finally when the abc system just starts rotating, it should have the same kinetic energy as the bc system AFTER the collision.

Answer (score 1):

The ball sticking to the rod says the collision is not elastic, so there is no energy conservation. Any time something is fixed together after a collision, the mechanical energy is not conserved

Comment: Yeah I'm aware. The collision itself is inelastic. But after the collision, there is no dissipation of energy as rod applies force only along it's length,i.e perpendicular to velocity.

Comment: did you use energy conservation after impact, or wich energy should be conserved?After the collision th thing turns an does not loos energy, only part of the energy of the ball before the collision is lost and turned to warmth.

Comment: Yeah I'm conserving energy after the collision. Initial k.e is 1/2*2m*(v/2)^2 which is just after collision and before rotation and final k.e is 1/2*3m*(l/2)^2*w^2. w is angular velocity when rotation starts

Answer (score 0):

When the ball C falls onto ball B, the potential energy of C is converted into Kinetic Energy of ball C at the moment that ball C hits ball B. After collision, energy is no longer conserved; it was an inelastic collision (energy is dissipated in the form of heat, presumably).

Comment: That is to say, energy is NOT conserved after the inelastic collision.

Comment: BUT momentum is still conserved after the collision

Comment: No.....after collision the blocks stick together.....alright initial energy of c is not conserved. But after collision when the bc system starts moving then the only force that can do work is the rod force. But it acts always towards the length, which is perpendicular to direction of motion. Hence we can conserve k.e

Comment: I'm conserving energy like....initial energy is before rotation but after collision. Final energy is JUST after rotation

Comment: But the thing is, the moment it collided, it also started to rotate. There's no "after collision but before rotation" moment. It happened very instantaneously.

Comment: See.....consider only the bc system first. After the collision it tries to move in the same path. At that moment the rod can't do anything to stop it as it can apply force only perpendicular to the direction of velocity. So the bc system tried to move linearly. But then it travels a small distance when the rod can exert an impulsive component along the direction of motion, hence causing a,b,c to altogether rotate.

Comment: Ah I see now; you used energy conservation from velocity of BC system right after they collide? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes absolutely right. If I conserve angular momentum in the same exact cases I get the correct answer. But if I apply energy conservation it fails